# Missing one line in ggplot2 line graph and highlighting particular data in line graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm working with some regional level data about household internet access in Latinamerica and the Caribbean, I made a df in order to use `ggplot2` to do some graphic representations of my data and I encountered some problems. This is my commented code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)
library(ggrepel)
library(gghighlight)

#Doing the dataframe with the data I want to visualize
df <- data.frame(
  'País' = c('Argentina', 'México', 'Colombia', 'Perú', 'Brasil'),
  "2017" = c(75.9, 50.7, NA_real_, 28.2, 61.0),
  "2018" = c(80.3, 52.5, 52.7, 29.8, 67.0),
  "2019" = c(82.9, 55.8, 51.9, 35.9, 71.0),
  "2020" = c(90.0, 59.9, 58.1, 38.7, 83.0),
  "2021" = c(90.4, 66.4, 61.6, 48.7, 82.0)
)
df

#There is no regional level data, so I create a mean of every column that would represent the regional mean
lac_row<-apply(df[,2:6], 2, mean, na.rm=TRUE)

#I paste the new row in the original df adding "LAC" in the "País" col

df<-rbind(df, c("LAC", as.numeric(lac_row)))

#Remove X
rownames(df) <- gsub('^X', '', rownames(df))

#In order to get a proper tibble to use with ggplot2 I use pivot longer to transpose my df into a longer format
df_long <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -País, names_to = "Año", values_to = "Porcentaje") %>%
  mutate(Year = as.numeric(str_remove(Año, "X")))

str(df_long)


# Create the ggplot
ggplot(df_long, aes(x = Año, y = as.numeric(Porcentaje), color = País, group = País)) +
  geom_line(size = 1) +
    labs(title = "Porcentaje de hogares con acceso a internet en Países de Latinoamérica",
       x = "Años",
       y = "Porcentaje",
       color = "País") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(scale = 1)) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("2017", "2018", "2019", "2020", "2021"))+
  geom_text_repel(aes(label = scales::percent(as.numeric(Porcentaje), scale = 1, size = 1)),
            nudge_y = 0.5,
            show.legend = FALSE,
            size = 3)+
  geom_point(size= 2.5)+theme_classic()
```

I got this warning messages:

```
Warning messages:
1: Removed 2 rows containing missing values (`geom_line()`). 
2: Removed 6 rows containing missing values (`geom_text_repel()`). 
3: Removed 6 rows containing missing values (`geom_point()`).
```

And this is my output:

[image]

As you can see, everything seems fine except for the LAC data, which is not shown properly, I would like its line to be drawn, and, additional to that, I would like that line to be slightly bold than the others (since is the regional mean).

Hope you can help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Looking, but (1) never do `df<-rbind(df, c("LAC", as.numeric(lac_row)))`, you are corrupting your data. You are trying to fix it with `as.numeric(.)` later, but you should not be doing that in the first place. It's better to `rbind` a frame (or list), names much match. (Consider `add_row` or `bind_rows` as alternatives.)

Comment: When I try your code, I see the LAC line, https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMKd1.png